Most efficient quadrature formula
On the integral I am looking to obtain an approximation with machine precision, I've thought about applying a Gauss-Jacobi formula or Gauss-Legendre for:
$$ \int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{2-x}dx $$
I am not sure if I can apply a Gauss-Jacobian formula considering the exponents to be $\alpha=1/2$ and $\beta=0$
That way turning this integral into
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}(1-t)^\frac{1}2dt$$
But this would mean considering our regular function $g(x)=1$
Is this possible? or is it correct instead to use a Gauss-Legendre quadrature considering our weight function $w(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{2-x}dx$ and then calculate the nodes? Is there any other formula that could be used to obtain machine precision?
Sadly my professor is not available to answer doubts.
Thank you in advance

$$\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{2-x},dx=4\sqrt{2}/3,.$$

I know the analytic answer but I need a method to calculate without using an analytic approach

Having the analytic answer allows you to try all numeric methods and see which is the best. What more would you want? No theoretician can give you a better answer.

@Moo this isn't machine precision.

A good source.

Do you have to code the quadrature yourself? There are existing packages for highly performant quadrature and many have adaptive subroutines that allow you to specify error tolerances

@whpowell96 Yes I have to code the quadrature myself
